# Laptop crashes with TexMaker

Tags: crash

It turns out that TexMaker, after compiling several times, crashes when I compile another one. First it appeared: "Error: file not found", and then TexMaker closes and then dozens of alerts of "Close Firefox" appear, and a tap with "Questions for Files" appears too. I haven't used TexMaker too much in this laptop, but I had never experienced this. When I try to compile a beamer, it's even worse: the whole laptop crashes, and lots of tabs with the "Questions for Files" appear. I add some screenshots.

[image]

[image]

[image]

I've recently installed (but I'd say TexMaker crashed before too) some `ubuntu-restricted-extras` , exactally [this](https://github.com/olejon/spotcommander/wiki/LocalFiles), for Spotify , just in case it has something to do.

The laptop is a bit dizzy these days, maybe because of that or maybe this was caused by other thing (it didn't recognize my password once, it indicated 18 hours of battery life - whereas I only have around 3).

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update.** I uninstalled and reinstalled Elementary Loki in my laptop, installed TeXLive 2017 (instead of TeXLive 2015 which is the version that appears in the repositories),... and the same issue happened again. My laptop crashed in the same way.

It seemed that using Gedit and by compiling in the command line it worked properly. I installed TeXStudio, and I even by forcing it I couldn't make it crash. It had to be TeXMaker... . Also, it only crashed when I made a quick build.

Thing is, my laptop is a Lenovo, and in order to compile quick I have to press Fn+F1. After adding a keyboard, I realized that it didn't crashed with it. So here you have. The problem came because I have to press Fn+F1 (funny thing, because in TeXStudio I had to press Fn+F6 and it worked).

**Solution.** I only had to change the "HotKey" Lenovo has in its laptops. It can be seen how to change the F1 key so you only have to press the F1 key instead Fn+F1 [here](https://support.lenovo.com/ec/en/solutions/ht072691).